# How do I change hyperlink colours in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, colors, url, presentation

I have a lot of Powerpoint slides that I converted to LibreOffice Impress.  The resulting hyperlinks are very faded, very hard to see. I can't seem to find any way to change the colour of hyperlinks as a whole.

Any colour change I do make on an individual url link does not hold when converted back to .ppt which is sometimes necessary.

I have tried the tools=options=libreoffice=appearance route but it only seems to affect the very first hyperlink in the slide set

Answer (score 13):

### Styles and Formatting window

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Editing_Hyperlinks

> Change the attribute of all hyperlinks
>
> Open the Styles and Formatting window.
>
> Click the Character Styles icon.
>
> Right-click the "***Internet Link***" or "***Visited Internet Link***" character style, and choose Modify.
>
> In the dialog, select the new attributes, and click OK.

### Notes

- Character Styles icon = button on top of the styles and formatting window

  [image: Character Styles icon in Libreoffice]
- Changes should be made to "***Hyperlink***" too (if you used or converted from a Microsoft Office Word document).
- In order to make changes to a text, select the text you want to change and double-click (left-click) on a character style (e.g. "Hyperlink").

Comment: @AttilaLendvai libreoffice draw is a drawing program, it doesn't have to do with writing, therefore I think that character styles doesn't exist for draw. Also, you could try the new 4.1.x versions. If you use ubuntu 12.04 you can try using this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-1

Comment: it's a drawing program, but it has textboxes, which i would expect to behave the same as writing text in Writer. but it's not an urgent issue for me, so i'll just wait an check the next time i need it...

Comment: same goes for impress, which the original question is about. There seems to be no "Character Styles" interface in recent versions of LibreOffice (4 or 5).

Comment: Impress [does not yet have Character styles](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40871), so this answer is literally incorrect.

Comment: apologies, I'm not sure if this was valid at the time. I must've been thinking of ms office word/libreoffice writer. you are definitely right though, nowadays it's not applicable.
I'd remove it, but seems just people upped this, so I guess it does provide an answer even for the wrong question

Answer (score 8):

There are two places which control the internet or index link color -- see image:

1. Tools > Options > APPEARANCE > Unvisited Links, Visited Links
2. Format > Styles and Formatting > Character Styles ("a in box" icon) > Index Link, Internet Link

My document is using Index Links which were blue and which I wanted to be black.  I changed the Index Link character style to be Black but only some of them changed.  Then I found the Appearance controls under Tools>Options and by turning the Links colors off it worked.

http://nsol.altervista.org/alterpages/loofficechangelinkcolor.png#gallery

Comment: Completely outdated answer.

Comment: The top voted answer did nothing for me, but going through tools > options, fixed it

Comment: It's now under Tools > Options > Application Colors

Comment: outdated answer look below my answer

Answer (score 6):

> Tools > Options > Application Colors

Then scroll down to "Unvisited links" and "Visited links"

Comment: This newer answer was correct for LibreOffice 6.0. Note that this setting will change only the color of new hyperlinks.

Comment: This is the correct answer for newer versions of libreoffice (7.0.4.2)

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools, then choose Options. From there, a window should pop up and one of the selections is Appearance under the LibreOffice tab.  A checkbox displaying the colours for a visited or unvisited link can be changed.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are two places which control hyperlink colors in LibreOffice

1. to format all your hyperlinks on the whole document

> Tools > Options... > Application Colors > Visited Links ...and set the color
> Tools > Options... > Application Colors > Unvisited Links ...and set the color

[image]

2. to format a particular hyperlink on your document

> Format > Character... > Hyperlink (in the Tab) > Character Styles (in the box) then set the color by choosing the "source text" for  example then personalize the hyperlink's style

[image]